# Using SnapEngage methods in Angular Component throws an error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using SnapEngage widget for my application. The application has Angular Components and functions in it. I am trying to use SnapEngage methods (), but it doesnt invoke/recognize those methods. Please clarify if I should have a plugin/imports from SnapEngage. I am getting error as Cannot find name 'SnapEngage'. at the line SnapEngage.allowChatSound(true);

```js
includeSnapEngageWidget(){    
    if( SnapEngageEnabled ==="true"){
 
        var se = document.createElement('script'); 
        var userEmail = email;
        var userName = name;
  
        se.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        se.async = true;
        se.src = '//storage.googleapis.com/code.snapengage.com/js/'+ widgetId +'.js';
        var done = false;
        se.onload = (se as any).onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (!done&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState==='loaded'||this.readyState==='complete')) {
            done = true;
            /* Place your SnapEngage JS API code below */
            SnapEngage.allowChatSound(true);
           
          }
        };
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s);
    }
  }
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating an external *.js file and its *.d.ts file, referred the *.js file path in angular.cli.JSON under scripts. The imported the function in main.ts file and called the method inside angular.

Answer (score 0):

If your application cannot find `SnapEngage` that means that js file wasn't loaded. Make sure that the call to `'//storage.googleapis.com/code.snapengage.com/js/'+ widgetId +'.js';` has succeeded when your application is loaded.

Comment: I could load the SnapEngage widget and chat - without the line   SnapEngage.allowChatSound(true); If I add it, I get the error. "Cannot find name 'SnapEngage'."